# Application_Start timeout?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax

I have one piece of code that gets run on `Application_Start` for seeding demo data into my database, but I'm getting an exception saying:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

While trying to enumerate one of my entities `DB.ENTITY.SELECT(x => x.Id == value);`

I've checked my code and I'm not disposing my context before my operation,  Below is an outline of my current implementation:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   SeedDemoData();
}

public static void SeedDemoData()
{
   using(var context = new DBContext())
   {
       // my code is run here.
   }
}
```

So I was wondering if `Application_Start` is timing out and forcing my db context to close its connection before it completes.

Note: I know the code because I'm using it on a different place and it is unit tested and over there it works without any issues.

Any ideas of what could be the issue here? or what I'm missing?

Comment: that error often means you are accessing some lazy-loaded property in an object that you have fetched from EF in a place where the context is disposed. Are you certain the exception is thrown from your SeedDemoData function?

Comment: Have you tried adding `ToList()` to your query within `SeedDemoData()` just to make sure your query is called before the context is disposed?

Comment: Yes, the exception is coming from my SeedDemoData(), what I tried to do is moving the DB.ENTITY.SELECT(x => x.Id == value) to be the first line in the execution and it works, but if anything else is executed on my context before this it will blow, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours investigating the issue I found that it is being caused by the data context having pending changes on a different thread. Our current implementation for database upgrades/migrations runs on a parallel thread to our App_Start method so I noticed that the entity I'm trying enumerate is being altered at the same time, even that they are being run on different data contexts EF is noticing that something is wrong while accessing the entity and returning an incorrect error message saying that the datacontext is disposed while the actual exception is that the entity state is modified but not saved.

The actual solution for my issue was to move all the seed data functions to the database upgrades/migrations scripts so that the entities are only modified on one place at the time.